# Excel macro to merge multiple sheets to mastersheets based on the sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, merge

So, I have one excel workbook containing around 80 sheets, the sheets are named as Input, Input(1), input, INPUT, INPUT(2) and Output, Output(1), Output(2), output, OUTPUT and so on, you get the idea... I want to create a macro which creates two mastersheets in the Workbook named "MASTERSHEET INPUT" and "MASTERSHEET Output". The macro should copy all the data from any sheet having any variation of input in its sheet name and paste it one into the MASTERSHEET INPUT and the same goes for the sheets named output which will be pasted into MASTERSHEET OUTPUT. I'm relatively new to VBA and I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out.
Thanks in advance!

This is the code I was using previously

```
 Sub CombineData()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)

    ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet"

   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange

        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If

        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
    Next

 End Sub
```

But this merges all the sheets in the workbook into one without checking the sheet name.

I tried using this one next but this just pastes the first Output sheet into both mastersheets and then ends:

```
 Sub CombineData()

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)

    ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet Output"

   For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
        
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange

        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If
        For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name = "OUTPUT*" Or xWs.Name = "output*" Or xWs.Name = "Output*" Then
             
        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
        End If
        Next
        
    Next

On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)

    ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet Input"

   For I = 3 To Sheets.Count
        Set xRg = Sheets(1).UsedRange

        If I > 2 Then
            Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
        End If
        For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name = "INPUT*" Or xWs.Name = "input*" Or xWs.Name = "Input*" Then
             
        Sheets(I).Activate
        ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xRg
        End If
        Next
    Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
Call DeleteAllSheetsExceptMaster

End Sub
```

I also tried using this but this does absolutely nothing:

```
Sub CombineData()
  

    Dim I As Long
    Dim xrg As Range
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim xWs1 As Worksheet
    Dim xWs2 As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
        
        For counter = 1 To 2
        Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
        If counter = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet Input"
        Set xWs1 = ActiveSheet
        End If
        
        If counter = 2 Then
        ActiveSheet.Name = "MasterSheet Output"
        Set xWs2 = ActiveSheet
        End If
        
        Next counter
        
        For I = 2 To Sheets.count
        
            Set xrg = Sheets(1).UsedRange
        
            If I > 2 Then
                
                Set xrg = Sheets(1).Cells(xrg.Rows.count + 1, 1)
            
            End If

        Sheets(I).Activate
        
            If Sheets(I).Name = "OUTPUT*" Or Sheets(I).Name = "output*" Or Sheets(I).Name = "Output*" Then
             
                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xWs2
                    
            End If
        
            If Sheets(I).Name = "INPUT*" Or Sheets(I).Name = "input*" Or Sheets(I).Name = "Input*" Then
             
                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy xWs1
                    
            End If
        Next
        
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Stackoverflow will help you when you get stuck writing your code. But we won't just write all the code for you.

Comment: Hey @Marc sorry for being unable to provide the code last time, could you help me out now?

Comment: Can you tell us about the data in the worksheets. Is it in one contiguous range? Does it have the same number of columns in each worksheet? Do you need only the values, or do you also need the formatting? Does it have headers? And anything else that you might consider relevant.

Comment: All input sheets have the same headers and same number of columns in each worksheet, output sheets have varying numbers of columns but the first nine columns are same, the changes start after that , only the values are needed formatting is not necessary. All data in input is present as a contiguous range as for output the first nine columns are contiguous but the rest aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Create Master Sheets

- The following will delete each of the master worksheets if they exist and then create new ones. Then it will copy the data from the current region starting in A1 of the defined source worksheets to the appropriate master worksheets (read OP's requirements).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub createMasterSheets()
    
    ' Define constants incl. the Names Arrays and the workbook.
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"
    Const tgtFirst As String = "A1"
    Dim srcNames As Variant
    srcNames = Array("iNpUt", "oUtPuT") ' Case does not matter.
    Dim tgtNames As Variant
    tgtNames = Array("MasterIn", "MasterOut")
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Define lower and upper subscripts of the 1D arrays:
    ' srcNames, tgtNames, Dicts
    Dim sFirst As Long
    sFirst = LBound(srcNames)
    Dim sLast As Long
    sLast = UBound(srcNames)
    
    ' Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Add Target Worksheets.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    For n = sLast To sFirst Step -1
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(tgtNames(n))
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wb.Sheets(tgtNames(n)).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
        wb.Worksheets.Add Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
        ActiveSheet.Name = tgtNames(n)
    Next n
        
    ' Define Dictionaries Array and populate it with Dictionaries.
    ' The Dictionaries will hold the Data Arrays.
    Dim Dicts As Variant
    ReDim Dicts(sFirst To sLast)
    Dim dict As Object
    For n = sFirst To sLast
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Set Dicts(n) = dict
    Next n
    
    ' Declare variables.
    Dim wsName As String ' Current Worksheet Name
    Dim rng As Range     ' Current Source Range, Current Target Cell Range
    Dim m As Long        ' Subscript of Current Data Array in Current Dictionary
                         ' of Dictionaries Array
    
    ' Write values from Source Ranges to Data Arrays.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        wsName = ws.Name
        For n = sFirst To sLast
            If InStr(1, wsName, srcNames(n), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                ' Define Source Range. You might need to do this in another way.
                Set rng = ws.Range(srcFirst).CurrentRegion
                m = m + 1
                Dicts(n)(m) = rng.Value ' This will fail later if one cell only.
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
    Next ws
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim Key As Variant ' Current Key in Current Dictionary
                       ' of Dictionaries Array.
    
    ' Write values from Data Arrays to Target Ranges.
    For n = sFirst To sLast
        Set rng = wb.Worksheets(tgtNames(n)).Range(tgtFirst)
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(tgtNames(n))
        For Each Key In Dicts(n).Keys
            rng.Resize(UBound(Dicts(n)(Key), 1), _
                       UBound(Dicts(n)(Key), 2)).Value = Dicts(n)(Key)
            Set rng = rng.Offset(UBound(Dicts(n)(Key), 1))
        Next Key
    Next n
    
    ' Turn on screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Sheets created, data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
                
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.

Edit: fixed case sensitivity.

```
Sub CopyFromWorksheets()
    Dim wrk As Workbook 'Workbook object - Always good to work with object variables
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'Object for handling worksheets in loop
    Dim trg As Worksheet 'Input Master
    Dim trg2 As Worksheet 'Output Master
    Dim rng As Range 'Range object
     
    Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook 'Working in active workbook
     

     'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
    Set trg = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
     'Rename the new worksheet
    trg.Name = "Input Master"
    'Add new worksheet as the last worksheet
    Set trg2 = wrk.Worksheets.Add(After:=wrk.Worksheets(wrk.Worksheets.Count))
     'Rename the new worksheet
    trg2.Name = "Output Master"
         
     
     'We can start loop
    For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
         'If worksheet in loop is the last one, stop execution (it is Master worksheet)
        If sht.Index = wrk.Worksheets.Count - 1 Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf LCase(sht.Name) Like "*" & "input" & "*" Then
                Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp))
         'Put data into the Master worksheet
        trg.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
        ElseIf LCase(sht.Name) Like "*" & "output" & "*" Then
                Set rng = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 1), sht.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp))
         'Put data into the Master worksheet
        trg2.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
        End If
               
        
    Next sht
     'Fit the columns in Master worksheet
    trg.Columns.AutoFit
    trg.Rows(1).Delete
    trg.Columns.AutoFit
    trg2.Rows(1).Delete

End Sub
```